# Binding real time data without reloading the page in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having a API which sends real time data and I want to display the data in my view without refreshing the page.
`setInterval` doesn't work in my case as the response time from API may be delayed and I don't want to reload the component.

Is there any solution to work around:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.realTimeData()
}

realTimeData(){
  this.http.get(api)
    .subscribe(res => {
       this.bindData = res;
    })
}
```

Comment: How does your api send real time data ? You'd need sockets or RPC for that as far as I know. The http observables go cold after the data is received so I think you'd need to keep it hot with one of the rxjs multicasting operators

Comment: @ihorbond I will check multicasting operator. No idea about that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the interval observable operator of rxjs.
This is a little example:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
... 
sub = Observable.interval(10000)
    .subscribe((val) => { <your code here> });
```

Also you can stop it unsuscribing of it with:

`this.sub.unsubscribe();`

Or use `timer` of `Observable`:

```
timer = Observable.timer(10000);
this.timer.subscribe((t) => this.<your method>());
```

Comment: How's it different from `setInterval`? Sometimes my api call takes 2mintues to get the data

Answer (score 1):

Polling an `http` endpoint on interval:

You can use either [timer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) or [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) rxjs creation operators to emit and  trigger an API call.

```
  realTimeDataSubscription$: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.realTimeData();
  }

  realTimeData() {
    this.realTimeDataSubscription$ = timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(switchMap(_ => this.http.get(api)))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.bindData = res;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.realTimeDataSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

It is always recommended to put `http` calls in service file and inject to component.

Comment: Why did we use `pipe` and `switchMap` here? Can you please explain that bit?

Comment: `switchMap` here is used to cancel all previous calls if they take more than a 1000ms and make a new call.

If your API call takes more time, then the best operator to use is `exhaustMap`.

`exhaustMap` will not make new API call until the old API call is resolved